# Border on subplots in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

How can I put borders (a box) around subplots in MATLAB?

I've tried the following but am unable to get the box around the image.

```
ax2 = subplot(1,2,1);
him = imshow(img, 'Parent', ax2);
box(ax2,'on');
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that `imshow` actually *hides* the axes object underneath. As a result you won't see the axes bounding box. To show this box, you'll want to turn on the axes visibility.

Also to get the same visual effect as imshow (except for the box), you will want to remove all x and y tick marks.

```
set(ax2, 'box', 'on', 'Visible', 'on', 'xtick', [], 'ytick', [])
```

[image]

Comment: @user6029533 You're welcome. If this solved your problem, consider marking it as the answer to help others with a similar issue.